# Zoom effect to scroll able Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

[image]

I have layout in that it contain a horizontal scroll scale.

My question is how make this type of zoom effect on the center of the layout?
Is it possible?
i have draw the scale in canvas and zoom the canvas??

Please help me.
Thank's in advance.

Comment: first of all  draw the scale friend .... zooming is easier

Comment: @CaptainAmerica drawing on the canvas is not big issue.issue is how to zoom the scale on canvas??

Comment: using canvas u can capture location of ur rectangular scale as bitmap so that u can zoom the bitmap easily friend... i had already did this ....

Comment: See this answer, it should do exactly as you require:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442934/magnifying-part-of-the-canvas-when-touched/11450800#11450800

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a Transformation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Transformation.html

The code in your onDraw method will look something like this:

```
canvas.save();
transformation.transform(canvas);
drawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: At first draw the scale(drawing) on a canvas.

Step 2: get the zooming region, and apply this region as the clipRegion on the canvas ..

Step 3: get the bitmap from the canvas, and draw it on the canvas applying scale on it,scaling pivot point will be the center point of the area you want to zoom,

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
Bitmap bitmap_object = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, conf); 
Canvas canvas_object = new Canvas(bitmap_object);

/* now  draw your drawing on canvas_object */

Bitmap temp = bitmap_object;

Matrix matrix_object = new Matrix();

/* now set transform and scale on matrix_object to zoom */

Paint paint_object = new Paint();
paint_object.setFilterBitmap(true);

Region reg= /* region of your zooming area */
canvas_object.clipRegion(reg);
canvas_object.drawBitmap(temp,matrix_object,paint_object);
```