# Touch point zoom preview

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, preview

I am working on scan Document program where i have already developed a program which scan document with image processing and give option to crop image same like CanScanner.

Now I want touch image zoom preview just like cam scanner gives option. How will i achieve this feature.
Please find attached image for reference (same feature i want to develope)

Please help to achieve this feature.

Thanks in advance
[image: Reference image for feature]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and use a `BitmapShader` (using the bitmap of the image you're drawing), a `Matrix` and a `Paint`.

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
mShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);

mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setShader(mShader);
```

Then setup a gesture motion event to record the touch position. We will set up the shader's matrix base on this position in the next step.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction(); 

    zoomPos.x = event.getX();
    zoomPos.y = event.getY();

    switch (action) { 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        zooming = true;
        this.invalidate();
        break; 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        zooming = false;
        this.invalidate();
        break; 

    default: 
        break; 
    }

    return true; 
}
```

Then in the drawing code, use `postScale()` to scale and translate the matrix base on coordinate of the crop region. Then draw a circle to display the magnifier using the shader Paint.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (zooming) {
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y);
        mPaint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(matrix);

        canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y, 100, mPaint);
    }
}
```

See: [Android - How to circular zoom/magnify part of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864480/android-how-to-circular-zoom-magnify-part-of-image) and [Magnifying part of the canvas when touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442934/magnifying-part-of-the-canvas-when-touched)

Comment: Hi nhoxbypass, I have created a magnifier zoom preview, but some how it does not show zoom preview of exact point, some pixel discrepancy is there.

Comment: @AlokSoni you should ask new question because it will attract more people, remember to capture device screen and put the code that you used there.

Answer (score 0):

To zoom the image you're drawing on the canvas:

Create a BitmapShader (using the bitmap of the image you're drawing), a Matrix and a Paint:

```
shader = new BitmapShader(bmp, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
matrix = new Matrix();
shaderPaint = new Paint();
shaderPaint.setShader(shader);
```

On a touch event record the touch position (e.g. in a PointF):

```
zoomPos.x = event.getX();
zoomPos.y = event.getY();
```

...and set up the shader's matrix (I do this on each touch, there's probably a better way):

```
matrix.reset();
matrix.postScale(2f, 2f);
matrix.postTranslate(-zoomPos.x, -zoomPos.y);
shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
```

Then in the drawing code, draw a circle using the shader Paint.

```
canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y, size_of_the_circle, shaderPaint);
```

Hope it helps! Happy coding!